# Install SOAP on PHP 5.4.13

Tags: php, linux

We recently started using MediaTemple for our hosting and only just realized that SOAP is not enabled in the PHP build. None of us are very experienced system admins so we asked MediaTemple whom provided the [guide here](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1947/Configure+PHP+with+SOAP#dv). The unfortunate thing is that we're using PHP version 5.4.13 and this guide is for 5.3.5.

I've tried to google installation instructions for our version of PHP, but can't seem to find anything.

How should I proceed with this? I'm contemplating downgrading the PHP version if needed but that's a whole mission in itself that I'm worried about.

Thanks!

Comment: really? the Soap classes are a core library; I'm really surprised it's not included -- it would have to have been deliberately removed when they configured it, and I can't think of any good reason for doing that. Anyway, don't downgrade -- that's not the answer. The instructions look generic enough that they should work for later PHP versions too; just change the version number. The thing is though, if you've manually installed it like that, upgrading later will be just as hard, and it's important to keep up to date with PHP security patches.

Comment: one possible alternative route you could try -- there is a third-party SOAP library for PHP called nuSoap. It's quite old, but it should work. If you haven't already written your code using PHP's soap classes, it might be worth a try to save yourself the hassle of messing with your php installation.